Making population density map in QGIS
I have a CSV file of Red Squirrel trail cam sightings. The file has multiple sightings for each trail cam location and includes date, time and location.
Using the Heatmap symbology gives me a good representation of the population density but the underlying Map (OSM) is not visible. If I change the white end of the ramp to full transparency the core area shows up well but the peripheral (lower density) areas do not show at all.
Is there a way to give weighting to the heatmap so that lower-density areas are visible or would another method give the the desired result?

Would setting the opacity of the layer as a whole help? Expand 'layer rendering' in the symbology screen and play around with it. I usually use 50%-ish.

I found 'Point Displacement' and setting 'Placement method' to Grid gave a better representation of the population than 'Heatmap'.
